# Can I force Json.NET to start tree deserialization from root

Tags: c#, tree, json.net, tree-traversal

This is my first attempt to serialize/deserialize tree. It works perfectly except for the `Path`. It must be built up from the root, but deserialization starts from leaves.

```
    var root = new Node(null, "rootName");
    var tree = new Tree(root);
    root.AddChild("childName");
    var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tree, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    var treeRestored = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tree>(str);

...

class Node
{
    public IReadOnlyList<Node> Children => _children;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Path { get; } // needs parent

    [JsonProperty(ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)]
    public Node Parent { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public Node(Node parent, string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Parent = parent;
        Path = (parent == null ? "" : (parent.Name + ".")) + name;
        _children = new List<Node>();
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    private Node(string Name, List<Node> Children)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        _children = Children;
        foreach (var child in _children)
        {
            child.Parent = this;
        }
    }

    public void AddChild(string name)
    {
        _children.Add(new Node(this, name));
    }

    private readonly List<Node> _children;
}

class Tree
{
    public Node Root;

    public Tree(Node root)
    {
        Root = root;
    }
}
```

So I tried the following. I removed `JsonProperty` from `Parent` property, changed serialization command, and changed JSON constructor.

```
    var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tree, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });

    [JsonConstructor]
    private Node(string name, Node parent)
    {
        Name = name;
        Parent = parent;
        if (Parent != null) // Rebuild path
        {
            parent._children.Add(this);
            Path = parent.Name + "." + Name;
        }
        else
        {
            Path = Name;
        }
        _children = new List<Node>();
    }
```

With these changes in place, serialization string looks this way:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Root": {
    "$id": "2",
    "Children": [
      {
        "$id": "3",
        "Children": [],
        "Parent": {
          "$ref": "2"
        },
        "Name": "childName"
      }
    ],
    "Parent": null,
    "Name": "rootName"
  }
}
```

This Json string contains enough information to first create the root, then the child. But JsonConverter still starts from leaves. How can I change the order?

I know that I can use `OnDeserialized`, but this is the last resort for me.

Comment: Well, I don't understand anymore what your problem is, I think you should review and reformulate your question so it's clearer.

Comment: @Aybe I want to DEserialize tree from the root. And I provided an example problem.

Comment: You mean you want to deserialize from X root ? If so then, don't even use `Tree` class at all but serialize your root node directly, that's what I do in here and it works. e.g. `JsonConvert.Deserialize<Node>...`

Comment: @Aybe it doesn't work for me. Maybe you can create live-example with my code as a base?

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the problem is that you are attempting to use a parameterized constructor with `PerserveReferencesHandling.Objects`, which is [documented](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) not to work:

> **Note:**
> References cannot be preserved when a value is set via a non-default constructor. With a non-default constructor, child values must be created before the parent value so they can be passed into the constructor, making tracking reference impossible. [`ISerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1) types are an example of a class whose values are populated with a non-default constructor and won't work with `PreserveReferencesHandling`.

Here's what I would do instead:

1. Remove the parameters from the private `[JsonConstructor]`, and make that constructor simply initialize the children to an empty list.

   ```
   [JsonConstructor]
   private Node()
   {
       _children = new List<Node>();
   }
   ```
2. Add private setters to both `Name` and `Parent` and mark them with `[JsonProperty]` so that Json.Net can use the private setters:

   ```
   [JsonProperty]  // allow Json.Net to use private setter
   public Node Parent { get; private set; }

   [JsonProperty]  // allow Json.Net to use private setter
   public string Name { get; private set; }
   ```
3. Don't store the `Path` in your object; instead calculate it on demand.  This is just one line of code and it is fast because it walks *up* the chain.

   ```
   [JsonIgnore]
   public string Path
   {
       get { return Parent != null ? Parent.Path + "." + Name : Name; }
   }
   ```
4. (Optional, but recommended) Make your `AddChild` method return the `Node` it creates-- this will make it much easier to use when creating the tree.  Otherwise you always have to search the list of children to find the node you just added.

   ```
   public Node AddChild(string name)
   {
       Node node = new Node(this, name);
       _children.Add(node);
       return node;
   }
   ```

Here is what your class would look like after all the changes:

```
class Node
{
    public IReadOnlyList<Node> Children => _children;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Path
    {
        get { return Parent != null ? Parent.Path + "." + Name : Name; }
    }

    [JsonProperty]  // allow Json.Net to use private setter
    public Node Parent { get; private set; }

    [JsonProperty]  // allow Json.Net to use private setter
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Node(Node parent, string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Parent = parent;
        _children = new List<Node>();
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    private Node()
    {
        _children = new List<Node>();
    }

    public Node AddChild(string name)
    {
        Node node = new Node(this, name);
        _children.Add(node);
        return node;
    }

    private readonly List<Node> _children;
}
```

---

If calculating the `Path` on the fly is too expensive, you could try the following ideas:

1. Use lazy evaluation.  Calculate the path the first time it is accessed, then cache the result locally for faster subsequent retrieval:

   ```
    private string _path;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Path
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (_path == null)
            {
                _path = Parent != null ? Parent.Path + "." + Name : Name;
            }
            return _path; 
        }
    }
   ```
2. Immediately after deserialization, walk the tree and request the `Path` for each node, forcing it to be calculated and cached.  Then it will be cached for every node.

   ```
    void PrecachePaths(Node node)
    {
        var path = node.Path;
        foreach (Node child in node.Children)
        {
            PrecachePaths(child);
        }
    }

    var treeRestored = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tree>(str);
    PrecachePaths(treeRestored.Root);
   ```

Comment: I can't calculate `Path` on demand. Calculation of property in my real program is very expensive.

Comment: What makes it so expensive?  Have you actually benchmarked this?

Comment: Awful, this constraint is awful and unreasonable. But this means that I can't do it in a nice way anyway. I tried to avoid private setters. Thanks for pointing me to this.

Comment: You know what, I'm not sure you understand this quote properly. With a child it might mean something different. Because it preserved references and called my non-default cons happily.

Comment: But another approach with calculation on the fly can be viable if combined with caching.

Comment: Yep, I just extended my answer to that effect.

Comment: But it still adds private setter. Life is hard.

Comment: It's a minor price to pay, IMO.  What can you do?  With respect to the note from the documentation-- maybe it will call your constructor, but it might not always have all the information it needs at the time.  So your mileage may vary.  You can try it of course, but I would be wary.